# What would be the best way to keep a balance current in a $_Session variable

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement, header

I have this small script at the top of a page. i want the page to redirect if the balance is 0, if it is not 0 id like the page its on to execute. As it is here , it ignores the if statement regardles if its true or not, and if i keep exit(); in nothing executes. Help me out guys

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../../includes/connection.php');

$id=$_SESSION['id'];

$select_query=@mysql_query("select balance from players_signup where id=$id");
$_SESSION['balance']=@mysql_result($select_query,0,'balance');
//echo "$",$_SESSION['balance'],".00";

$balance=$_SESSION['balance'];  

if($balance<"1"){
  header('location:../../paypal/');
  exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: the <?php is in the original script, i missed it on the copy and paste

Comment: Why do you make the balance a session?

Comment: @small legend, thats my primitive way of apply the balance to other areas of the site where needed, id just like it as a option, Why? do you suggest other ?

Comment: have you checked for errors? have you checked what the db is returning? stop suppressing errors then wonder what the porblem is, stop using depreciated mysql_*

Comment: no errors, i see the the values when i print the session variables, regardless if the value is less then 0 or greater then , the if statement does not execute, Also, i appreciate the advice about depreciated mysql , im aware of that, that isnt whats causing the issue.its not a database or query issue

Answer (score 0):

Firstly *mysql_* is deprecated, use **mysqli_**

*Then use something along these lines*

```
//conn is the connection value

$checkBalance = $conn->query("SELECT balance FROM players_signup WHERE id= '$id'");
$row= $checkBalance->fetch_assoc(); 
$balance = $row['balance'];
```

Then your if statement

*"i want the page to redirect if the balance is 0"*

```
if($balance ==0){
    header("location:.....");
}
```

Refer to : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

*It has helped me vastly*

**You have 1 as "1", remove the quotes**

Comment: The query isnt the issue, i see the balance reflect in print sessions, trust me the live site will not have the depreciated query's, i have to redo what someone has done in terms of the old mysql BUT ,thats not my focus nor problem

Comment: removing the quotes didn't do it, the quotes have worked for me in past

Comment: can u simulate in jfiddle

Comment: I got it guys,a file that was included was conflicting